# How to prevent UglifyJS from dropping an unused function when processed by WebPack?

Tags: webpack, minify, uglifyjs

I have a fairly small script that controls a carousel inside a modal. To launch the modal, I have a simple `showModal()` function that gets called when an image on the page is clicked. 
However, this function is getting stripped by UglifyJS when the JS files is processed by WebPack. Here is a simplified outline of the code:

```
$('#iconified').on('keyup', function() {
var input = $(this);
input.addClass('empty');
});

var carouselVideoPlayer = (function() {
var initialized = false;
var videoCarousel;

function initCarousel() {
    videoCarousel.carousel({
        interval: false
    });
}

return {
    init: function() {
        initCarousel();
        initialized = true;
    }
  };
})();

function showModal(slideNumber) {
  $('#myModal0').modal('show');
  carouselVideoPlayer.showSlide(slideNumber);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var thumbnails = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    thumbnails.push($('#carousel-selector-' + i));
  }
  carouselVideoPlayer.init();
});
```

I have tried to use the mangle option with `showModal` reserved and I have tried using the `/*@__PURE__*/` comment in front of the function. Short of making a dummy call to this function, I just want to mark it as need or ignored so UglifyJS won't strip it out and cannot seem to find a simple way to do this.

***Updated***
While not what I was hoping for, the following will stop UglifyJS from stripping out the function.
Added an if statement to `showModal()` and have a call to it in my initialize method, passing in -1.

```
function showModal(slideNumber) {
  if (slideNumber !== -1) {
    $('#myModal0').modal('show');
    carouselVideoPlayer.showSlide(slideNumber);
  }
}
```

Comment: Added a dummy call, but I feel like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with how to configure Web Pack, but setting the unused flag to false as part of the Uglify compression options would likely solve this problem.

See the compression options documentation here:
https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compress-options

Your workaround turns the function into one that is being used, so it doesn't get deleted after the change you mentioned above.

Comment: That may work. I ended up refactoring the whole thing to work with a check in the main JS code. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: If someone does try this and it works, please up-vote.